# Failed to generate API key for Dglobal ID via web admin panel

Tags: api, http

I am trying to generate an api key in Dglobal ID to be able to connect to my account to allow my users to register with Dglobal ID. A page should appear where you can request the api key in order to make the POST request.

Generate an api token to authenticate my users with Dglobal ID making a post request. The page appears blank with an error code that says the request could not be processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate an api key with Dglobal you have to visit id.dglobal.dev login with your account or create a new one and visit your developer page there you have to go to "Developer options" and generate your api key.

I hope that solved your question.